# Pivot wider to account for duplicates

Tags: r, count, pivot

My dataset associates a single application number with a range of different applicants. The state in which each of these applicants lives is listed in a column.

I want to transform my dataset so that:

- the application number column only features distinct values,
- each state has its own column
- the number of applicants linked to the application is counted in their respective state column

e.g.

| appli.number | State |
| --- | --- |
| 600000 | AK |
| 600000 | AK |
| 600000 | AL |
| 600000 | AL |
| 600000 | AL |
| 600001 | AK |
| 600002 | MA |
| 600002 | MA |
| 600003 | AL |

> > > > > 

| application number | AK | AL | MA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 600000 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 600001 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 600002 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 600003 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I thought it should use pivot_wider and count functions but I am relatively new to R and still haven't yet got my head around lots of stuff.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
  data <- tribble(
  ~appli.number,    ~State,
  600000,   "AK",
  600000,   "AK",
  600000,   "AL",
  600000,   "AL",
  600000,   "AL",
  600001,   "AK",
  600002,   "MA",
  600002,   "MA",
  600003,   "AL"
)


table(data)
```

or if you want to use `pivot_wider()`

```
library(tidyverse)    

data %>%
  group_by(appli.number, State)  %>%
  count()  %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "State", values_from = "n", values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I didn't expect it to be so simple!